# equivalent to [obj class] in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, class, equivalent, anyobject

How to get the class of an anyObject type in Swift?

In Objective-C we can get it like so :

```
id obj = [obj class]
```

Comment: Swift is not an acronym. It's written "Swift", not "SWIFT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of [obj class] in SWIFT is :

```
obj.dynamicType
```